# react: вопрос проектирования компонента, который будет отображаться (использоваться) лишь при соблюдении некоторых условий

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

создал компонент `ComponentBottom`, который используется внутри компонента `ComponentTop`:

```
// компонент ComponentTop
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <какие-то элементы />
            {this.state.flag ? <ComponentBottom /> : <></> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

у меня такой вопрос новичка - в таких ситуациях лучше добавлять возможность отображения компонента в сам компонент:

```
// компонент ComponentTop
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <какие-то элементы />
            <ComponentBottom show = {this.state.flag} />
        </div>
    );
}

// компонент ComponentBottom
render() {
    if (!this.props.show)
        return <></>

    return (/*отрисовка компонента*/);
}
```

или оставлять всю логику отрисовки в родительском компоненте как это было указано выше?

какой подход лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нет объективного ответа. И все зависит от нескольких факторов.

1. Какой объем у дочернего компонента.
2. Есть ли у него состояние.
3. Как часто условие будет меняться.

Если компонент большой и содержит также огромное количество компонентов и/или стейта, то конечно делать условный рендеринг через родителя это не лучшее решение даже несмотря на то, что Реакт сейчас быстрый. Учтите что в таком коде каждый раз компонент будет создаваться с нуля.

```
{this.state.flag ? <ComponentBottom /> : <></> }
```

И если он огромный, есть вероятность что это даже повлияет на скорость отображение вашего UI. В таких случаях всегда пишите условный рендеринг внутри компонента.

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.show)
        return <></>

    return (/*отрисовка компонента*/);
}
```

Согласен что писать внутри компонента условия это выглядит не красиво, но в таком случае компонент не будет создаваться каждый раз с нуля. С точки зрения скорости и перформанса приложения второй вариант лучше в больших компонентах.

Если это небольшой JSX компонент без стейта, то можно смело писать через тернарный оператор или через оператор `&&`. Кстати, [осторожно с оператором `&&`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored).

Comment: компонент не большой, состояния есть, но не много

на счет красивости - ну так и тернарный оператор тоже не очень красив местами :)

Comment: @Zhihar слово "не большой" относительно. Для кого-то не большой это 2000 строк кода компонента.  Для меня компонент не должен содержать больше 300/400 строк кода и не должен делать больше одной операции (принцип единственной ответственности). Если у нас одинаковое понимание слово "не большой", то используйте тернарный оператор или оператор `&&` в 9 из 10 случаев :)